# Select next column based on label reference to columns of pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
import pandas as pd, numpy as np

df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(10, 4)), columns=['a','qww12','b','hdbh'])
```

If I have to select columns 'a' and 'b' I do the following:

```
sublist=['a','b']

df2= df1[df1.columns.intersection(sublist)]
```

Is there a simpler way to select columns next to 'a' and 'b' without having to type out the names? Actually I am fetching the data from excel sheet and the names can change and can have white spaces.

Thanks in advance.

Expected output

```
   qww12  hdbh
0     18    86
1     84    67
2     23    45
3     60    15
4     82    60
5     84    75
6     24    23
7     34    79
8      4    45
9      2    82
```

Comment: "select columns next to 'a' and 'b' without having to type out the names" what do you mean by that?

Comment: Can you add expected output to this question?

Comment: In this case, I want columns 'qww12' and 'hdbh'

Comment: So need `df2= df1.loc[:, ~df1.columns.isin(sublist)]` ?

Comment: `Is there a simpler way to...` You're line of code is not doing what apparently you want to do, so this statement is misleading

Comment: @jezrael I want to choose neighbouring columns. columns next to column names specified by sublist

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`get_indexer()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#ix-indexer-is-deprecated) for this to get the index of the `sublist` and add `1` to get the next column index, then use [`df.iloc[]`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html):

```
df1.iloc[:,df1.columns.get_indexer(sublist)+1]
```

---

```
   qww12  hdbh
0     48    91
1     86    67
2     21    98
3     11    94
4      9    14
5     70    54
6     38    61
7     99    65
8     16    86
9     15    40
```